# Weird wavy lines

Tags: rendering

I'm sorry I can't really provide a ton more info for this question besides just screenshots, because I wouldn't even know where to begin but:  anybody know why I'm getting these weird horizontal lines?:

[image]

They are not visible in the solid view:

[image]

And I only have a basic lighting setup and scene (3 area lights, nothing in between the lights and this object, simple plane in background.  Blender 2.9, and just a basic scene I dropped the objects into.  The material is just a very basic material I made by saying add material and then setting the color.  No nodes or textures or anything.

These two questions seem to be the same problem:  [strange black lines on object when rendered](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/130689/strange-black-lines-on-object-when-rendered/130697#130697)
[Why do these weird lines appear in my render?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/186419/why-do-these-weird-lines-appear-in-my-render?rq=1)

But none of the solutions offered seem to fix it (setting the origin point or scaling)

Comment: It looks like duplicated or overlapping faces, causing z-fighting

Comment: I can't seem to find any duplicated or overlapping faces, though i won't say that couldn't be the cause.  Just nothing apparent when i go inspect closely in edit mode or anything

Comment: Could this be related? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/130689/strange-black-lines-on-object-when-rendered/130697#130697

Comment: Edit:  I said the solutions from the other questions didn't work but one of them KINDA did.  Applying a scale to my lights didn't necessarily do anything, but when i radically increased the size of the lights it did fix it.  From 0.1m to 10m   (the whole object is huge at the moment).   So maybe it was some sort of mismatch between light size and what it is lighting up?

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason that they are there is because they are in the shadows and the image is very noisy. If you up the sample rate it should get rid of the lines. Could you link the blend file?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't link to it as the bones are real live patient data (and names of objects and stuff include PHI, would be a pain to get rid of).  As I said in one of my comments, increasing size of the light seemed to fix it.